# reverse output of list in the view

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to reverse order of the outputed list:

[image]

These items were being added as Global:Contextual links in the View, but order is wrong. Instead of going and replacing in each view (lets say that there are 100 views), what would be the quickest way of reversing order and making it like :

- Manage display
- Clone
- Access Control
- Delete
- Edit

Thanks

Comment: ....what's CCL?

Comment: ooops no ccl. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement the [hook_menu_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) and adjust the links `weight` property to your will. Here is a sample code that changes the node's default contextual links by placing the delete link over the edit link:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function foo_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/delete']['weight'] = 0;
  $items['node/%node/edit']['weight'] = 1;
}
```

Keep in mind that the smallest the `weight` of a link the more will flow on top, negative numbers may also be used.